# Transmitting an RS232 Signal over Wireless/RF. Can this be achieved?

Tags: pcb, rf, cmos, rs232, modulation

I have an idea I am trying to implement and I want to know if this is possible and feasible.

I have a Barcode Scanner device that gets connected to a PC with a DB9 COM port. Using this connection and a Terminal software which is mapped to the COM port, we send basic serial commands with the RS2232 protocol to this scanner.

However, on the company production floor I am not able to connect the PC and Scanner together since they are about 20 meters apart and it is not possible to route the DB9 Cable to connect the PC to the device.

I am thinking to connect the Transmit pin of the Com port on the PC to an RS232 to CMOS converter on a PCB to convert this signal to a 5V TTL Signal, then send this TTL signal to a RF Transmitter module. The idea is, the signal information is transmitted to a RF receiver module, which outputs a 5V TTL Signal with the same information as the original signal. Then this TTL Signal which is the original command from the Terminal software, is now converted to RS232 and sent to the Scanner.

Can this be achieved? I know I will need to use some kind of modulation to transmit the TTL/CMOS Square wave over Radio Frequency.

IF this is indeed possible can anyone give me some pointers what components I need to successfully implement modulation and how I can preserve the information of the original serial command that was sent using the Terminal software?

Comment: There are many RS-232 transparent radio transceiver modules on the market.

Comment: I am not familiar with this actually, so I don't really know  what is involved. Does the Transceiver module require software programming or configuration? How would the the module communicate with the Terminal software on the PC and send the same information to the device?

Comment: Have you done any research if something that is certified to operate in a work setting already exists?

Comment: There are serial over WiFi, over Bluetooth, over ZigBee, what not. You just need to define better what you want and do a little bit of research. You can even have your endpoints on the opposite sides of the globe and have them connected via Internet.

Comment: @kvj Modules will have different configuration settings, but my understanding is some can operated right out of the box. They output UART (and sometimes other formats as well) so for one to work with a PC you would need a USB-UART bridge (in chip, board, or integrated cable form) and virtual COM port drivers installed on the PC.

Comment: But for your specific problem, an extra computer or laptop connected to the scanner and some software creating virtual serial port over wifi between the computers will do just fine. Or just Remote Desktop to it. Just a bit of creativity. Some keywords: `com0com`, `tcp2com`, `com2tcp`

Comment: Can't connect a computer to the Scanner in the production environment. Not possible to route and many space constraints.

Comment: @kvj If you can connect a wireless RS232 transceiver box to it, you surely can connect a Raspberry Pi, Arduino, or an Intel NUC to it as well. Or at least you don't specify how much space you have.

Comment: Why connect a Arduino to the device if I can connect the Radio Modem Box? The Radio modem solution works. Yes Initially I was looking at a Microcontroller/PCB based solution since I was not aware of the Radio Modem. Although I would like to know and understand how a TTL Signal can be  modulated send over wirelessly to another device.

Comment: @kjv see the update to my answer. Data transmission can get rather complicated, but hopefully my basic explanation will help.

Comment: I have been using HC12 and found it good: https://www.elecrow.com/download/HC-12.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A device that does this is called a [Radio Modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_modem). They work like a phone modem, but using RF instead of audio.

You basically connect your RS-232 devices to them, and set up the communication protocol.

The way data is sent over a modem is by converting it into a bitstream, the data is encoded so that it can be transmitted one bit at a time, and the bits are used to modulate a signal. Early modems did this by using different tones for high and low, while an RF modem modulates an RF signal, which can be done in a number of ways.
One of the most basic ways of sending data over RF would be FSK, Frequency Shift Keying, where the RF switches between two frequencies to indicate high or low bits.

Comment: Thank you. I think the Radio Modem seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

In a production environment, you can't afford stuff that doesn't work.

If both ends of the wireless transmission are 20m apart, then the user on one end won't be able to see the screen of the computer on the other end. He won't know if the transmission succeeded or not. So he will rely on feedback from his side. If the computer or scanner on his side says the transmission was completed, for example with a beep, but the other side hasn't received it, he won't know.

This means the transmission must be error-free and guaranteed to succeed. That's not difficult to do over 20m. Serial ports are quite slow, which means the extra latency from retransmitting a packet that was lost won't be noticeable. But the wireless RS232 adapter has to support it, which means you can't use any dumb transmitter.

So, I would recommend purchasing a pair of wireless RS232 adapters that explicitly support this.

If you want to DIY, you could use any micro that supports a radio protocol that allows error-free guaranteed transmission, for example WiFi with an ESP32. Or you could implement error-free transmission with a micro and a nRF24L01. But there is no reason to DIY this stuff when a large number of devices that will do the job are available at a reasonable cost.